# concatenate string with prop value received in react/Javascript in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

how to concatenate a string with a variable's value in javascript (more specifically react).In this ToolsCard component, I am getting the title as prop and I want to make a string 'download title which is being received as prop, how should I do this.I tried the below way but I am getting an error, Is there some alternative to do this?

```
const ToolsCard = ({title}) => {
const str='download'+{title}
}
```

Comment: What error? That function doesn't seem to return anything (are you expecting it to be a React component?) and it looks like you're mixing up string template literals with _object_ literals.

Comment: You are destructuring the title object, so I assume whats left of that is a string. Since whats left is just two strings, you can just 'download' + title. Skip the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const ToolsCard = title => 'download ' + title;
```

I don't know what else to tell you. You might want to export the ToolsCard function maybe. And you should definitely read some Javascript and React tutorials.